# Javascript\Node.JS Scraping Logic, finding time in string

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, web-scraping

I am trying to create a scraper that goes through local sites, and gets event information.  I am having problems pulling event times because everyone enters it in which a different format.  Anyway, I was wondering if there is a good way to look for one of these "am, a.m., p.m., pm) and then get any numbers before the am or pm.

I know there is something like this but it isn't dynamic enough.

```
var rawTime = "String blab la bla 10:00 p.m.";
toParse = rawTime.substring(rawTime.indexOf('p.m.') - 6);
```

Would the best bet be to find the indexOf, create an array, and have a while loop go "backwards" till a space or non-number is returned?

But then I would run into issues with people typing out 10:00p.m. and 10:00 p.m. Since there is a space before p.m.

Answer (score 0):

Best is to use a regular expression since it supports exactly the kind of fuzzy pattern matching that human entered times require.

```
/\d{1,2}(:\d{2})?\s*([ap][.]?m[.]?)?/i
```

Would do and it'd support 10a.m and 9am too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of code that will work for your examples.

```
var ts = [];

ts.push('String blab la bla 10:00 p.m.');
ts.push('String blab la bla 10:00 pm');
ts.push('String blab la bla 10:00 am');
ts.push('String blab la bla 10:00 a.m.');

for(var i=0; i<ts.length; i++){
    var match = ts[i].match(/(\d+:?\d+)\s?[ap]\.?m/) || []
    console.log(match[1]);
}
```

Here is the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2qA6e/1/

You may have to make it more robust to catch all use cases, but I believe I satisfied your 4 examples.

Edit: Updated to only return numbers. Added Use Case

Answer (score 0):

I am not a regex master, but hopefully this will help you:

```
var rawTime = "String etc 10:00 p.m. etc etc"
var result = rawTime.match(/(0?[1-9]|1[012]):([0-5]\d)[ ]?([APap].?[mM].?)/);
if (result)
{
    alert('Hour: ' + result[1] +
          '\nMinute: ' + result[2] +
          '\nAM/PM: ' + result[3].replace(/\./g, '').toUpperCase());
}
```

The regex above will match basically any way of expressing the meridian indicator, upper or lower case as well as with or without periods (and with or without a space after the minutes). It also basically validates that it's a real time AM/PM time (although note that you would want to tweak it for 'military' time, e.g. 14:15 instead of 2:15 PM)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote something out, I am not sure if my logic is correct. I think it should pick up almost any format.  The only issue is if the string has a number before it for example a price... then it might get strange trying to think of a work around for that.

```
var re = /(a.m.|p.m.|pm|am)/g, // Filter By 
str = "String blab la bla 10 to 12:00 a.m. asdfasdfas"; // String To Test

var timeArray = new Array();
var timeStamp = new Array();

while ((matcher = re.exec(str)) != null) {
    timeArray.push(matcher.index);
    timeStamp.push(matcher[0]);
}

// Get Start And End Time
startTime = str.substring(timeArray[0] - 6, timeArray[0]);
finishTime = str.substring(timeArray[1] - 13, timeArray[1]);

if (startTime.length == 2) {
    finishTime = startTime.substr(1,2);
    startTime = startTime.slice(0,1);
} else {
console.log(finishTime);
var matches = /(-|to|till)/g;

if (finishTime.match(matches) != null) { 

    var splitTime = startTime.split( matches );
    var slpitTimeFinish = finishTime.split( matches );

    if (timeStamp.length > 1) {
        finishTime = slpitTimeFinish[2].replace(/[A-Za-z$.]/g, "");
        startTime = splitTime[0].replace(/[A-Za-z$.]/g, "");
    } else {
        finishTime = slpitTimeFinish[2].replace(/[A-Za-z$.]/g, "");
        startTime = slpitTimeFinish[0].replace(/[A-Za-z$.]/g, "");
    }

    startTime = startTime.replace(/\s+/g, ''); // Remove Spaces
    finishTime = finishTime.replace(/\s+/g, ''); // Remove Spaces

} else {
    finishTime = finishTime.replace(/[A-Za-z$.]/g, "");
    finishTime = finishTime.replace(/\s+/g, ''); // Remove Spaces

    startTime = startTime.replace(/[A-Za-z$.]/g, "");
    startTime = startTime.replace(/\s+/g, ''); // Remove Spaces

 }
}

// Get Time Stamp

if (timeStamp.length > 1) {
    eventStartStamp = timeStamp[0];
    eventEndStamp = timeStamp[1];
} else {
    eventStartStamp = timeStamp[0];
    eventEndStamp = timeStamp[0];
}


console.log ("Event Starts At "+ startTime + " " + eventStartStamp +" Ends At "+ finishTime + " " + eventEndStamp );
```

Here are some tests I ran, If anyone has any better ways, or suggests their methods, I am all ears.  This might be over-coded.

```
str = "String blab la bla 12a.m. to 1pm asdfasdfas";
returns "Event Starts At 12 a.m. Ends At 1 pm

str = "String blab la bla 12-1pm asdfasdfas";
returns "Event Starts At 12 pm Ends At 1 pm


str = "String blab la bla 12:00a.m. to 1:00 p.m. asdfasdfas"
returns "Event Starts At 12 am Ends At 1 pm



 str = "String blab la bla 12:00 to 1:00 p.m. asdfasdfas"` 
 returns "Event Starts At 12:00 p.m. Ends at 1:00 p.m.


str = "String blab la bla 12:00 - 1:00 p.m. asdfasdfas" 
returns "Event Starts At 12:00 p.m. Ends at 1:00 p.m.
```

Should also work if someone puts in for example 7-10p.m.  I just need to figure out how to get rid of anything before the time, which in this case could possibly happen. I guess this will get a decent amount of good data.  Let me know if anyone has a better solution.  I know this is a big over coded, I can cut it down a bit, I am just more visual than most.